# How to extract folder's name (a series number ID) in R?

Tags: r, file, directory

I have got a large number of folders containing CSV and htm files. Each folder has an unique folder name as ID. I am wondering would it be possible extract folder names?

Comment: Is `list.dirs()` what you need?

Answer (score 4):

For any directory path string, you can use:

```
fullpath = getwd()
directoryname = basename(fullpath)
```

For a whole range of directories:

```
manydirectories = list.dirs()
directorynames = basename(manydirectories)
```

You only need to omit the "." in `directorynames` to then get the folder names within that directory.